# No Controllers menu item on the Asp.net core 5.0 Web API project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-5.0

> Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019
> Version 16.9.4
> Windows 10 Pro

Any clue why I cannot see the Controllers menu item? This is the Asp.net core 5.0 Web API project

MS Doc says this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#scaffold-a-controller

But I cannot see that?

[image]

New items has this:

[image]

**Update**

`CinamaApi.csproj`

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="5.6.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Controllers\" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

[image]

Comment: I believe its not available in dotnet 5 because its not forced to hold it in the controller folder unlike .net framework

Comment: @misha130 It is there: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#scaffold-a-controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**OP's feedback**

Need to install `ASP.NET workload` when install/update the VS

***Ref:*** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/367671/no-controllers-menu-item-on-the-aspnet-core-50-web.html

**Original**

Based on the icon of your project, your project is not an API.

Go to your .csproj file and edit the first line into

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
```

Then you will scaffold item in your context menu

[image: https://i.gyazo.com/5bfe3c5e5f7a6b740fd89e6545fc5ba5.png]

After a reload your project icon should become like this:

[image: https://i.gyazo.com/637f959069fa085cc0c94e7eb90a7dac.png]

Comment: Please see `Update`. I have it already. i.e. I didn't change it manually. Can you share the version of your Visual Studio?

Comment: Did you reload the projects after making the change? Its clear from the icon of your project its not a Web one. Its supposed to be like this: https://i.gyazo.com/637f959069fa085cc0c94e7eb90a7dac.png

Comment: As I mentioned earlier where this is the default one. I didn't change anything. Does it seem where this is a bug on the latest version? I have notified them too: https://twitter.com/VisualStudio/status/1384947041667883012

Comment: I am on the same version 16.9.4. I doubt its a bug

Comment: Hmm.. Have you installed anything through Nuget?

Comment: No, nothing like that. Can you add your project properties to check if it's not a class library accidentally?

Comment: Done. Please see it.